# Пропал локальный диск. Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

Мне принесли ноутбук, был забыт пароль от входа, я открыл пользователя Администратор и удалил учетку на которой был пароль. Как оказалось, пропал раздел, на котором было 130ГБ. Вопрос: может ли удаление учетной записи удалить том?

Я проверил через параметры компьюетра - пустоты\незарезервированного раздела нет.(у меня была проблема, что под линукс было выделено 200гб, переехал на винду - 200гб пропало. Но они были в настрйоках как незарезервированный раздел)

Comment: *может ли удаление учетной записи удалить том?* Если он был зашифрован - да. Причём если он был шифрован средствами ОС, то восстановить его уже не получится.

Comment: @Akina скажите пожалйуста, а возможно ли, что том зашифровала сама система? Просто пользователь обычный и таких манимпуляций произвести не мог и уж точно не знал как.

Comment: Юзер - существо творческое. Обычному юзеру пошифровать том - раз плюнуть, кликнул куда не надо в свойствах тома, и даже не понял, что сделал. А вот ОС - существо безынициативное, и по собственному почину ничего делать не станет.

Comment: @Akina ну, может есть сборки с такими вот дефолтными настроками. Спасибо за информацию

Comment: Сильно сомневаюсь в существовании таких кастомных сборок. И гарантирую, что в официальных дистрибутивах такой ерунды, как дефолтное шифрование тома, нет.

Comment: Дополнительно. Поскольку на диске нет (если Вы не ошибаетесь) нераспределённого либо неподключенного на букву пространства - не исключаю, что это был том, которых формируется из файла на основном томе. Рекомендую попробовать найти этот файл (по размеру). Он мог, впрочем, лежать и в папке профиля, если Вы и папку удалили - соболезную. Но если файл найдётся - определите по его имени/расширению/структуре, какая софтина его создала, сравните со списком имеющегося на станции программного обеспечения...

Comment: Может это корпоративный ноутбук? И "пропавший" том был томом iSCSI? Соответственно вне корп. сети том исчезает